# Entity Framework trouble querying ManyToMany relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have three Entity classes.

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.Locations = new HashSet<Location>();           
    }    
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }       
}

public partial class Location
{       
    public Location()
    {            
        this.People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public int CityID { get; set; }           
    public virtual City City { get; set; }                    
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public partial class City
{
    public City()
    {
        this.Locations = new HashSet<Location>();
    }    
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }                         
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to query my entities and get all the locations of a given person.
So far i have this method.

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetLocationsForPerson(int id)
    {
        return context.People
                .Include(p => p.Locations)
                .Where(p => p.PersonID == id);

    }
```

which is working fine.The problem is that i want to get the name of the city for each location too. while i am getting the cityID from Location table, the City property of Location entity is returning null. Why is that null? and how can i modify my query to get the City Name? Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
.Include(p => p.Locations)
```

With:

```
.Include(p => p.Locations.Select(l => l.City))
```

In EF Core you also do:

```
.Include(p => p.Locations)
   .ThenInclude(l => l.City)
```